# Running swing program gives white screen in home computer

Tags: java, swing

When I compile and run a swing program at school it works perfectly fine, but when I run it at home I am getting just a solid white color inside the frame. Does this have anything to do with different Java versions or OS?  At school I use windows XP and at home I use windows 8.

Comment: It is most likely that the code is broken, and while one JRE reveals that, the other does not.

Comment: I would check the Java console to see if there are any exceptions. It's hard to say if you're running the same Java version on your home computer and at school.

Comment: See also [*Initial Threads*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

Comment: I had this exact problem when I wrote my first Swing program, and it turned out to be due to a multithreading bug in my code.